# Extract data from a file using patterns from a second file

Tags: bash, perl, awk

I have two files:

**`file1`**:

```
hello,bad,bye
hello,good
bad,please
```

**`file2`**:

```
hello
bye
please
```

I want to extract the lines of `file1`, but not the entire line:  only the parts of each line that match terms given in `file2`.

Summarizing, my desired output from the above two files would be:

```
hello,bye
hello
please
```

I would like to do this in `bash`, `awk` or `perl` but I can't think of a simple/efficient way to proceed.

Comment: are they always comma separated? can you show your attempts to see how far you are from the solution?

Comment: Yes, always comma separated. OK, I'll try to show some attempt but it is a bit messy. The thing is that I can not see a good approach to deal with the issue. Maybe to many hours in front of the pc.

Comment: Don't use the word "pattern" as it's very ambiguous. What do you mean by a "match"? Is it a string comparison or regexp comparion (e.g. does `a.c` "match" `abc`)? Is it full or partial (e.g. does `he` "match" `them`)? Does that apply in both ways or just one way between the files? If the match occurs multiple times on an input line do you want it multiple times on the output line or just once? If there's no match should a blank line be output or nothing? Edit your question to show sample input/output that you think are hard to handle, not just a couple of trivial sunny day cases.

Comment: I thought that with the example all these questions were clear. And I put a trivial sunny day case, because actually it is, instead of words I have gene names, but I guess this is not relevant. Thank you for the advices.

Comment: No, the example addresses none of my questions, hence my asking them.

Comment: Hello @cucurbit :-) the files you are processing seem similar [to one of your earlier questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26890652/append-a-new-column-to-file-in-perl). How large are the data sets you are working with and how many "match" terms are you searching for with each pass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perl solution. Keep the known words in a hash, use [split](http://p3rl.org/split) to extract elements from the comma separated lists, filter them with [grep](http://p3rl.org/grep).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $SINGLE, '<', 'file2' or die $!;
my %known;
while (<$SINGLE>) {
    chomp;
    $known{$_} = 1;
}

open my $LIST, '<', 'file1' or die $!;
while (<$LIST>) {
    chomp;
    my @keep = grep $known{$_}, split /,/;
    print join(',', @keep), "\n";
}
```

Comment: ++ I forgot about this neat approach which checks to see if elements of an array exist in a hash of "known" search terms - does it have a name? The `%known` hash here seems a bit tricky at first (like the `%seen` idiom) but is really quite simple. With a large list of terms to match it clearly would be faster than building a regex as my response uses.

Answer (score 3):

`awk` solution: read the words from `file2` and then loop through the values in `file1`.

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR {a[$1]; next}
           {s=""
            for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
                 if ($i in a) s=(s?s FS:"") $i
            print s}' f2 f1
```

Note it needs some tweaking to handle commas, etc. If you don't care about trailing spaces and commas, just use

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR {a[$1]; next} {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i in a) printf "%s ",$i; print ""}' f2 f1
```

#### Test

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR {a[$1]; next} {s=""; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i in a) s=(s?s FS:"") $i; print s}' f2 f1
hello,bye
hello
please
```

Answer (score 1):

A Perl command line to test (cut and paste into Unix shell):

```
perl -lne 'BEGIN{ local @ARGV=shift; while(<>){ chomp; push @srch, $_ ;}
           $rx = join "|", @srch ; $rx = qr/$rx/; }   
           print join ",", grep { /$rx/ } split/,/, $_ ;'  file2 file1
```

**Output:**

```
hello,bye
hello
please
```

The command is similar to @choroba's approach only the "terms to match" from `file2` are read in a `BEGIN{}` block and made into a regex, and the "data" in `file1` are read in the [implicit while loop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches) created by the `-n` switch.

`@ARGV` is `shift`ed in the `BEGIN` block so `file2` can be read with `while(<>)` - there may be more elegant idiom for this.

Comment: Actively seeking alternatives to `BEGIN{ local @ARGV=shift; }` when dealing with multiple files on the command line. Comments welcome.